# Минимальная длина обрезки текста excerpt в wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Есть кастомный код, который обрезает the_excerpt() до первой точки.

```
function strpos_arr($haystack, $needle) {
    if(!is_array($needle)) $needle = array($needle);
    foreach($needle as $what) {
        if(($pos = strpos($haystack, $what))!==false)  $pos_arr[] = $pos;
    }
    return is_array($pos_arr) ? min($pos_arr) : $pos;
}
add_filter(
  'the_excerpt',
  function ($excerpt) {
    return substr($excerpt,0,strpos_arr($excerpt,array('.', '?'))+1);
  }
);
```

Проблема в том, что если первая точка слишком рано, например, предложение состоит из одного слова, то смотрится как-то не очень. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить в этот код возможность задавать минимальное кол-во символов до первой точки. Т.е. если первая точка ранее, чем заданное кол-во символов, то обрезка текста происходит на второй точке.

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/id_31/obrezka-teksta-zamenyaem-the-excerpt.html

Comment: Я видел тот код, но хотелось бы использховать тот, что я привел в вопросе.